# Electrical wiring and bulb

Tags: wiring

I have a chandelier with Leviton bulb sockets marked: 75W 125V

My first question is can I use 120V bulb instead of a 125V bulb?

My second question is in relation the wiring and whether 12 gauge wire with a 20 AMP breaker is okay to use with the Leviton bulb sockets marked 75 W 125V?

Answer (score 3):

On your first question, those are *rating limits*.

Look at your coffeemaker, "capacity 10 cups" etc.  Can you make 4 cups? Of course. They are saying if you put more than 10 cups, it won't work.  Your S-rated (112mph) car tires are also safe at lower speeds.  Etc.

125V is the max limit for the socket (due to insulation strength).   You don't get to choose the voltage in your house, the power company supplies 120V in North America.  This would be the wrong socket, say, for Europe where line voltage is 230V.

75W is the max limit for the socket (due to thermal heat from the bulb).  Since the ruling factor is *heat* not *light*, you are allowed to use any bulb less than 75 watts *actual*.  So if you have a 26-watt LED (bright like a 150W incandescent), that is fine since it's well under 75W.

On your second question, if your breaker is 20A, then use of 12 AWG cable is *mandatory* all the way from the panel to the ceiling box where the chandelier attaches.  This is another "rating-like" thing; you're perfectly welcome to use larger 10 AWG cable but you cannot use the smaller 14 AWG.

Answer (score 2):

You're fine on both counts.

120v household power in North America is +/- 5%, so 125v is effectively equal to 120v.

12 AWG wire is appropriate for a 20 amp breaker (assuming that the whole circuit is #12 or thicker), and that chandelier should have no problems. (Back of the envelope calculation has it that you could run about 32 of those on that one circuit.)

Comment: I agree on both counts higher voltage lamps last longer but do not produce as much light some manufactures play games to say there lamps last longer. A 120v lamp is the nominal voltage in the U.S. +